# How to pass 'as' argument to gdbus?

Tags: dbus, gdbus

This is a part of xml.

```
<method name="Mount">
  <annotation name="org.chromium.DBus.Method.Kind" value="simple" />
  <arg name="path" type="s" direction="in" />
  <arg name="filesystem_type" type="s" direction="in" />
  <arg name="options" type="as" direction="in" />
```

And this is what I want to implement exactly. (captured method call by dbus-monitor)

```
method call time=1675906347.661521 sender=:1.31 -> destination=org.chromium.CrosDisks serial=4557 path=/org/chromium/CrosDisks; interface=org.chromium.CrosDisks; member=Mount
   string "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1"
   string ""
   array [
      string "rw"
      string "mountlabel=MY-STORAGE"
   ]
```

And This is what I tried by gdbus.

```
gdbus call --system --dest org.chromium.CrosDisks --object-path /org/chromium/CrosDisks --method org.chromium.CrosDisks.Mount "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1" “” [“rw” "mountlabel=MY-STORAGE"]
```

The I got errors.

```
(gdbus call:12863): GLib-CRITICAL **: 23:37:56.454: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'g_utf8_validate (string, -1, NULL)' failed
[Invalid UTF-8] Error parsing parameter 2: expected value:
  \xe2\x80
  ^ 


(gdbus call:12863): GLib-CRITICAL **: 23:37:56.455: g_error_free: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
```

I think my expression for the `type="as"` is wrong.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
"['rw', 'mountlabel=MY-STORAGE']"
```